# Adding numbers to a grid C

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

So I am relatively new to C and have been practicing questions on it. So I came across the question, 'Where can I go?': http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/c-coding-java-c--c-coding-bouncy-string-tasked-write-program-take-parameters-command-line--q19411844

I manage to write a part of the code, but I am not sure how to get this

```
| | | |
| | | |
| | | |
| |X| |
```

I somewhat have the logic of when the counter for width = x - 1, counter for width = x + 1, counter for height = y - 1 (basically the first few steps that can be moved to from the starting position, X) the numbers placed there would be limit - 1.

Same for when it goes on
 for i less than or equal to limit
     the spaces between the limit - 1, will now be filled with limit - 2. So it will be like x-1 && y-1, y-2, y-1 && x+1, x+2 and so on until the last where 0 is placed.

But how do you write this and fix it in the for loop?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        int width, height, x, y, max;

        printf("Enter width: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &width);

        printf("Enter height: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &height);

        printf("Enter x: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &x);

        printf("Enter y: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &y);

        printf("Enter walking limit: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &max);


            int b = 0, a = 0;  // initalize local variable

            for (a = 0; a < height; a++) {

                    // fill the width
                    for (b = 0; b < width + 1; b++ ) {

                        printf("|");

                        if (b==x && a==y)
                            {
                                printf("X");
                            }else if(((b==x-1) && (a==y)) || ((b==x+1)  && (a==y)) || ((a==y-1) && (b==x)))
                                {
                                    printf("%d", max-1);
                                }else if(//i am not sure if this will be needed)
                        {
                            for(int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
                            {
                                //add max - i to spaces after C until max is over. 
                            }
                        }
                     }
                            printf("\n");
            }
            return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: `(a < height || b < width + 1)` is always true. `else if() ` ??  `;` after the line of `int` instead of `,` Please compile with warning and error

Comment: @Ôrel i edited the question as per your remarks :) i was not sure if the else if is needed hence left it empty.

Comment: Have you try to compil with error message ? `scanf("%d\n", width);` should be `scanf("%d\n", &width);` and all the other same way

Comment: @Ôrel oh yes sorry, i didnt copy and paste here and just wrote it out hence missed out the &. updated it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split your code in several functions.

I have done a quick example below.

First we need a function to display the array.
You need to create your array, see the malloc.
Then you set the max steps at the correct position.
Then you need a function to do the propagation, this is a very naive way to do.
Scan the array and set to the value minus one all the cell around.
Do it max times.

For example:

```
Enter width: 9
Enter height: 9
Enter x: 3
Enter y: 7
Enter walking limit: 3
| | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | |
| | | |0| | | | | |
| | |0|1|0| | | | |
| |0|1|2|1|0| | | |
|0|1|2|3|2|1|0| | |
| |0|1|2|1|0| | | |
```

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>



static void array_print(int *array, int width, int height)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        printf("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            int val = array[i * width + j];
            if (val < 0) {
                printf(" |");
            } else {
                printf("%d|", val);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


/**
 *
 * Update the array if x, y is inside the limit and
 * if val is greater than the already set value
 *
 */
static void
array_upate(int *array, int width, int height, int x, int y, int val) {

    if (x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height) {
        int prev = array[y * width + x];
        if (val > prev) {
            array[y * width + x] = val;
        }
    }

}

static void array_propagate(int *array, int width, int height)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            int val = array[i * width + j];
            if (val > 0) {
                array_upate(array, width, height, j, i - 1, val - 1);
                array_upate(array, width, height, j, i + 1, val - 1);
                array_upate(array, width, height, j - 1, i, val - 1);
                array_upate(array, width, height, j + 1, i, val - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int width, height, x, y, max;
    int *array;

    printf("Enter width: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);

    printf("Enter height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    printf("Enter x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter y: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    printf("Enter walking limit: ");
    scanf("%d", &max);

    /* allocate the array */
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);

    /* Set all to -1 */
    memset(array, -1, sizeof(int) * width * height);

    /* set the start to max */
    array_upate(array, width, height, x, y, max);
    /* do the propagation */
    while (max-- > 0) {
        array_propagate(array, width, height);
    }
    array_print(array, width, height);
    free(array);
}
```